# Trying to write efficient code to update Background Color using Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The following code works but I feel like there is probably a more efficient/cleaner way.  I'm new to Kotlin and Android Development so please go easy on me.  ;-)  Any enhancements would be much appreciated as I'm always looking to improve.

```
fun updateBackgroundColor() {

    val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    // Gets the text color from the shared preferences file
    val backgroundColor = sharedPref.getString("background_color", "")
    val fullscreenView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content)
    val fullView = fullscreenView as TextView?

    // Changes the text color based on the color the user has selected in Settings/Preferences
    if (backgroundColor == "blue") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlue))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "red") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mRed))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "green") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mGreen))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "yellow") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mYellow))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "purple") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mPurple))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "pink") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mPink))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "black") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlack))

    } else if (backgroundColor == "white") {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mWhite))

    } else {
        fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlue))


    }

}
```

Comment: Is this working code that you're looking for a code review for? If so, it might be a better fit for our [CodeReview.se] site.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I had no idea that existed.  I'll post there instead. Thanks!

Comment: My first thought, incidentally, is that this seems like Kotlin's equivalent of a `switch` statement may be somewhat easier to read here.

Comment: Yes, the Stack Exchange network is actually composed of quite a few different sites - they separated out questions about "broken" code (Stack Overflow) from methodology/architectural questions (Software Engineering SE), tool/library recommendations (Software Recommendations SE), and Code Review questions (Code Review SE), partially because of differences in moderating them. For example, tool/library recommendations are notoriously difficult to moderate well because they tend to draw spam and excessively opinionated answers.

Comment: I'll try to use ``when(){}`` (the ``switch`` of ``Kotlin``) and I'll avoid to write the same line each time.

Comment: One thing could be to use the `when` statement to decide which color to use and store it in a variable and then just call `fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, whateverVariableYouUsed))` once at the end (so that it's easier to tell that that's the thing that you're trying to decide about in the `when`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saving a string with the color, save the hex value of the color. Then you can avoid the massive if/else statement.

```
fun updateBackgroundColor() {
    val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    // Gets the text color from the shared preferences file
    val backgroundColor = sharedPref.getString("background_color_hex", "0x000000")
    val fullView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content) as TextView?

    // Changes the text color based on the color the user has selected in Settings/Preferences
    int color = Color.parseColor(backgroundColor);
    fullView?.setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

Also, you can do the findViewById as a oneliner, as shown above.
Using '!!' in Kotlin is EXTREMELY bad, as it basically says "i know this can be null, and i don't care, just crash if it's null", which is one of the main points of using Kotlin. So you should use '?' as shown above instead, as it'll run the code if it's not null, and if it is null, it won't run the code (which means it won't crash)

Comment: Dumb question - what's the easiest way to store it in hex in the first place?

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your code and comments helped me a lot.  So much cleaner!  I was able to take your code suggestion with a few minor tweaks and got it working in my app.  I'm now on the hunt for !! and will try to fix that in other parts of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` without using if & else. This `when` is like the `switch` of Java.

```
fun updateBackgroundColor() {    
    val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    // Gets the text color from the shared preferences file
    val backgroundColor = sharedPref.getString("background_color", "")
    val fullscreenView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content)
    val fullView = fullscreenView as TextView?

    // Changes the text color based on the color the user has selected in Settings/Preferences
    when(backgroundColor) {
        "blue" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlue))

        "red" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mRed))

        "green" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mGreen))

        "yellow" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mYellow))

        "purple" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mPurple))

        "pink" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mPink))

        "black" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlack))

        "white" -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mWhite))

        else -> fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, mBlue))
    }

}
```

Comment: Another thing you could do too is to use the `when` to set a variable with the color and then just call `fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, whateverVariable)` at the end - it's more lines of code but I think it's slightly clearer because that's the thing that's actually varying in the `when` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `map` like this:

```
var map = mapOf("blue" to mBlue, "red" to mRed, "green" to mGreen, ...)
fullView!!.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, map[backgroundColor]))
```